# Does PopupViewImpl in GWTP have setTitle method?

Tags: gwt, gwtp

I am trying to create PopupPanel in GWTP as following:

```
import com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.PopupViewImpl;
 public class MyPopupView extends PopupViewImpl implements
    MyPopupPresenter.MyView {
    ..... general code here...
}
```

But 1 strange thing is that, why Google didn't create a `setTitle` for `PopupViewImpl` object, which make the PopupView look really unprofessionally since there is no title.

Can you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `DialogBox` and return it in the `asWidget` method. The title for the popup can be set  using `DialogBox#setText` method.